# Creating count table in R by two variables

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Fruit_Type = c("Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Peach", 
"Peach"), Store_Bought = c("Walmart", "Walmart", "Aldi", "Walmart", 
"Walmart")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I want to count each fruit type by the store it was bought from. The desired output should be this:

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(Fruit_Type = c("Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Peach"
), Frequency = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Store.Bought = c("Walmart", 
"Aldi", "Walmart", "Walmart")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(Fruit_Type, Store_Bought) %>% summarize(Frequency = n())`

Comment: Thank you! I get an error message that says `Error in summarize(., Frequency = n()) : 
  argument "by" is missing, with no default`

Answer (score 1):

A solution using base R and the package `reshape2`:

```r
x <- xtabs(~ Fruit_Type + Store_Bought, df)
x
          Store_Bought
Fruit_Type Aldi Walmart
    Apple     1       1
    Banana    0       1
    Peach     0       2

# x is in "wide format". We use melt::reshape2 to convert into
# long format:

reshape2::melt(x, value.name="Frequency") -> xx

xx
  Fruit_Type Store_Bought Frequency
1      Apple         Aldi         1
2     Banana         Aldi         0
3      Peach         Aldi         0
4      Apple      Walmart         1
5     Banana      Walmart         1
6      Peach      Walmart         2

# This have two extra zero rows. Removing those:

with(xx, xx[Frequency>0,])
  Fruit_Type Store_Bought Frequency
1      Apple         Aldi         1
4      Apple      Walmart         1
5     Banana      Walmart         1
6      Peach      Walmart         2
```

Or if you prefer a one-liner:

```r
xtabs(~ Fruit_Type + Store_Bought, df) |> 
  reshape2::melt(value.name="Frequency")  |> (\(x) x[x$Frequency>0,] )()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using library(dplyr):

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(Fruit_Type, Store_Bought) %>%
       summarise(Frecuency = n()) %>% 
       relocate(Frecuency, .before = Store_Bought)
```